Two Ubuntu 22.04 laptops connected to the same IPv6 subnet, one works normally but the other one ignores IPv6 RA and failed to set default route
I'm administrating a IPv6 subnet that use DHCPv6 to assign IP and internal DNS. The router of this subnet is configured to send IPv6 RA with both M-bit and O-bit enabled, and both L-bit and A-bit in prefix section are enabled too.
Today we've added two laptops running Ubuntu 22.04 to the subnet. One is two years old and never updated; the other is just installed last week. Both are using default sysctl (doesn't including any configuration about net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra in /etc/sysctl.conf nor /etc/sysctl.d/*) and the network interface is configured use nmcli:
nmcli con modify NICNAME \
    ipv6.method "auto" ipv6.address "" ipv6.gateway "" \
    ipv6.ignore-auto-dns no ipv6.ignore-auto-route no ipv6.never-default no

The older one successfully acquired IP & DNS from DHCPv6, and set default route (local-link) from IPv6 RA, without any problem. The newer one only acquired IP & DNS, but failed to set default route.
Both are connected to the same L2 switch (no ACL, no VLAN). Basically all computers (including two macOS, two Rocky and older Ubuntu) connected to the same L2 switch are working as expected, except that newer Ubuntu.
I'm completely clueless. I can manually add default route via sudo route -A inet6 add ... command and force it to comply, but I really want to know what exactly is going on. Is there configuration that I can check ?
